# Flash: Repeat every 10 minutes

Tags: flash

I'm new to flash and created my first SWF file. I want to be able to repeat this flash once every 10 minutes.

I have been searching for a way to do this for half a day now, and I'm stumped. I'm hoping someone can help me. The closest I got was extending the timeline to 16000 frames, which is 10 minutes, but is there a better way to do this?. I want a 60fps file so using 16,000 frames only gives me 4 and a half minutes or so.

I'm using adobe flash professional.

Comment: You will want to use actionscript to achieve your goal. Specifically the timer class/event. Read more here: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3timer/

Answer (score 0):

You need a Timer to do this - using frames is impractical (if you can even get away with it without Flash locking up!)

```
var timer = new Timer(600000, 0);//600000ms (ten minutes), repeat count: 0 repeat forever)

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTick);//Add listener for timer complete

function timerTick(e:TimerEvent):void {
    //Code to start again here, possibly just 
    //gotoAndPlay(0) but can't see your file
}

timer.start();//Start the timer
```